# use control value accessor for nested form

Tags: angular, angular-controlvalueaccessor

I followed [this](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/) blog post.

Everything works, but I have a few questions regarding control value accessor if we implement a nested reusable form with it.

First, in the example the blog writer uses in the `registerOnChange` event an array for storing the subscriptions:

```
const sub = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(onChange);
this.onChangeSubs.push(sub);
```

1. Why does he use an array? If I use just a simple variable for storing the subscription, it also works. The question is not about storing and destroying the subscription.
2. Second question is, that in every example `emitEvent` is set to false in the `writeValue` method:

`this.form.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });`

Why is that? We want, that `statusChanges` and `valueChanges` triggers.

3. Although we define our sub form and the controls like a regular form:

   `form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({ addressLine1: [null, [Validators.required]], addressLine2: [null, [Validators.required]], zipCode: [null, [Validators.required]], city: [null, [Validators.required]], });`

But if I console log the main form:

```
mainForm = this.fb.group({
    userName: [''],
    address: [],
  });
```

I see, that the form controls in the `address` formgroup aren't really controls (the `address` form group has no `controls` property). They are just object entries with a value. Which means, that yes, we did a nested form group, but this is threated as a custom form control in a whole. So, basically with control value accessor we can implement reusable nested forms, but in fact, the inputs aren't really form controls. Am I right?

Comment: 1. convenience so that in the ngOnDestroy they can look and unsubscribe easily. 2. to prevent an infinite loop. Otherwise, we change a value here and parent updates, which gets passed down to this nested form and updates ad infinitum. I have a guess for 3 but I'm not confident enough to post (formGroup vs underlying ngModel)